# error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type in main file

Tags: c, struct, typedef, incomplete-type

Can you explain why the struct Test is incomplete and how to remove the error? Is the error related to declaration in test.h or to definition in test.c? I tried to move the definition code to header file but then createTest does not know type Test or if I move the function to header there is the error *multiple definition of `createTest`*

test.h

```
typedef struct STest Test;
```

test.c

```
typedef struct STest {
    int v;
    char *str;
}Test;



Test *createTest(int v,char *str) {
    Test *t=(Test*)malloc(sizeof(Test));
    t->v=v; // error
    t->str=str;  // error
    return t;
}
```

main function (main.c)

error:
main.c|44|error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Comment: In addition to the answers below, if you call `createTest()` from `main.c` you will also need the function prototype `Test *createTest(int v,char *str);` in `test.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't define the structure in the header file it will not be *visible* from your `main.c`.

You need to do the following

Point 1. Put the structure definition in the `test.h` header file. use *include guard* also.

```
#ifndef __MY_HDR_H_
#define __MY_HDR_H_
typedef struct STest {
    int v;
    char *str;
}Test;
#endif    //__MY_HDR_H_
```

[EDIT: Also, you need to add the function prototype for `createTest()` in the `.h` file]

Point 2. include `test.h` in `test.c` and `main.c`.

Point 3. Compile using

```
gcc main.c test.c -o output
```

Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family.

Comment: Thank you. I completely forget about this: "**include test.h in test.c**"

Comment: @user1141649 thank you for that. I wish the downvoter also had time to explain the error in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
typedef struct STest {
    int v;
    char *str;
} Test;
```

into `test.h`.

`typedef struct STest Test` only says that `Test` is another name for `struct STest`. At the moment, that's all that `main.c` knows. Especially, `main.c` doesn't know which members the struct has. That sounds quite incomplete to me.

Answer (score 0):

Place the code in the header file.

```
typedef struct STest {
int v;
char *str;
} Test;
```

Because compiler doesn't know to dereference that.

Hint: Then don't cast the result of malloc.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to define `Test` twice.

In test.h you do

```
typedef struct STest Test;
```

Inside test.c remove the `typedef` and just do:

```
struct STest {
  int v;
  char *str;
};
```

---

A full example below:

To define an opaque type, a type which is know in detail only to the translation unit implementing its functions, you might take the following approach:

opaque.h

```
#ifndef OPAQUE_H
#define OPAQUE_H

typedef struct S T;

T * createT(int, char *);


#endif
```

opaque.c

```
include <stdlib.h>

#include "opaque.h"

struct S
{ 
  int i;
  char * p;
};

T * createT(int i, char * p)
{
  T * t = malloc(sizeof *t);

  if (NULL != t)
  {
    t->i = i;
    t->p = p;
  }

  return t;
}
```

And use it like follows:

```
#include "opaque.h"

int main(void)
{
  T * t = createT(0, NULL);
}
```